# How should I wire this ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan, wire

I need to install a ceiling fan. I uninstalled the old one. there are 5 wires. and I was expecting just 3.

there are 2 white, 1 green, 1 blue and 1 gray wire.

[image]

the green wire and one of the white wires have the medal part.

[image]

also they both connected to the brown wire using the connector.

[image]

From this pic, you can see blue and gray wires connected to the big gray wire. white wire (without metal part) connected to the big white wire. and green and white wires (both has metal) connected to the brown wire.

[image]

First question, I need to find the grounding wire. Is that green one the ground wire? Is it safe to strip off the metal part.

[image]

second question I need find a black wire. however I only have blue and gray.  which one I should use?

[image]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: You should only have black, white, green, and maybe a red if you have a 2 way switch. Your other color wires I presume are from the remote control receiver. Pull your wires out of the box and look for the black, white an green or bare. From there connect the remote wires to the box wires as directed. Then connect the fan to the box as directed. Your instructions might have with and without the remote setup.

Comment: @JeffCates, after I removed those wire nuts, I have 3 wires left. copper, white and gray. I believe gray is the black wire and copper is the ground.  I was confused by those extra wires connected by wire nuts.

Comment: Yes, the gray is also a black, or hot wire. Now that you are back to the basics, start from there and if you have the remote setup, follow the directions for that!